# The data I am receiving from GET method is not being updated on html page

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to just show the Buyers Information (Model Class) by retrieving the data from a database using a web API on an angular app. The problem is that the data I am getting are not being displayed on the html page and I can't find a solution for it. 
Here is my service class:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'
import {Buyer} from'./buyer.model'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch'

@Injectable()
export class OneBuyerService {

  SelectedBuyer : Buyer;
  constructor(private http : HttpClient) {}
  postBuyer(buyer: Buyer)
  {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:54632/api/Buyers',buyer);
  }


  getBuyers(): Observable<Buyer[]>
  {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:54632/api/Buyers').map(res=>
    {
        let buyers = res;
        return buyers;
    })
    .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  getBuyersbyID(id: string): Observable<Buyer[]>
  {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:54632/api/Buyers/'+id).map(res => res).catch(this.handleError)
  }

  private handleError(error: any)
  {
    console.log('server error: ', error);
    if(error instanceof Response)
    {
      let errMessage = '';
      try
      {
        errMessage = error.statusText;
      }
      catch
      {
        errMessage = error.statusText;
      }
      return Observable.throw(errMessage);
    }
    return Observable.throw(error || 'ASP.net server error');
  }
}
```

Here is my Components Class:

```
import { Component,Input, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { OneBuyerService } from '../shared/one-buyer.service';
import { Buyer } from '../shared/buyer.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-buyer-list',
  templateUrl: './buyer-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./buyer-list.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class BuyerListComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() buyers : Buyer[];

  constructor(private oneBuyerService : OneBuyerService) {}
  loading:boolean = true;
  buyersList : Buyer[];
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getBuyers();
    //  const me = this;
    //  me.oneBuyerService.getBuyers().subscribe(res =>
    //   { 
    //     me.buyersList = res as Buyer[];
    //     this.loading = false;
    //     console.log(this.buyersList);
    //   });
  }

  getBuyers()
  {
    this.oneBuyerService.getBuyers()
      .subscribe((buyers:Buyer[]) => 
      {
        this.buyersList = buyers;
        this.loading = false;
      }, 
      (error: any) => console.log(error),
      () => console.log(this.buyersList));
  }

}
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div *ngIf="loading">
  Loading, Please Wait ...
</div>
<div *ngIf="!loading">
  <table class="table table-sm table-hover">
    <tr>
      <th>Full Name</th>
      <th>Credit</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody *ngFor="let buyer of buyersList">
      <tr>
        <td>{{buyer.FullName}}</td>
        <td>{{buyer.Credit}}</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger">X</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Here is the result and even if I remove the Loading part it still shows an empty table.
[image]

Comment: I edited the picture the first one was an old one sorry for that.

Comment: can you put a log on `subscribe` and check if ` this.buyersList = buyers;` is working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would bet the problem is with changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

Can you try to get hold of a reference in your constructor like below:

```
constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

And change your method like this:

```
getBuyers()
  {
    this.oneBuyerService.getBuyers()
      .subscribe((buyers:Buyer[]) => 
      {
        this.buyersList = buyers;
        this.loading = false;
        this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
      }, 
      (error: any) => console.log(error),
      () => console.log(this.buyersList));
  }
```

Also I don't think your HTMl is valid. You shouldn't put your ngFor on tbody.
Each table element should have only one tbody.

Move down your ngFor to tr element and it should work.

Like here

```
<div *ngIf="loading">
  Loading, Please Wait ...
</div>
<div *ngIf="!loading">
  <table class="table table-sm table-hover">
    <tr>
      <th>Full Name</th>
      <th>Credit</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let buyer of buyersList">
        <td>{{buyer.FullName}}</td>
        <td>{{buyer.Credit}}</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger">X</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Or if you want to generate new table for each buyerList then you have to put ngFor on table itself

Comment: The problem the table is not even showing at all like you can see in the picture because loading is staying true even though I am changing it in the subscribe. I did as you said and nothing changed

Comment: Please recheck my answer

Answer (score 0):

**Change `buyer.FullName` to `buyer.fullName` and  `buyer.Credit` to `buyer.credit` and `*ngFor` iteration should be done on `tr` tag not on `tbody` tag**

```
<tr *ngFor="let buyer of buyersList">
    <td>{{buyer.fullName}}</td>
    <td>{{buyer.credit}}</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger">X</button></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: The problem the table is not even showing at all like you can see in the picture because loading is staying true even though I am changing it in the subscribe.

Comment: can you confirm `loading` is false after `this.oneBuyerService.getBuyers()`

Comment: try console.log and confirm `loading` is `false`

Comment: if I change the console after the subscribe from logging the array of buyers to logging loading then it shows it as false but the table still doesn't appear

Comment: Try `*ngIf="loading == false"`

Answer (score 0):

Your console picture shows fullName and credit, but your code shows FullName and Credit.

Comment: even if I change them then loading is not being changed so the table is not showing at all

Comment: As another issue I see is that you have the subscription in the component. I recommend to store the buyersList in the Service and retrieve the list in component with a get.

Comment: I added another answer for this

Answer (score 0):

Using get...

In Component:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.oneBuyerService.loadBuyers();
}

get buyersList(): Buyer[] {
  return this.oneBuyerService.buyers;
}
get loading(): boolean {
  return this.oneBuyerService.loading;
}
```

In service:

```
buyers: Buyers[];
loading: boolean;

  loadBuyers()
  {
    this.http.get('xxx')
      .subscribe(
        (buyers:Buyer[]) => {
          this.buyers= buyers;
          this.loading = false;
        }, 
        (error: any) => console.log(error),
        () => console.log(this.buyersList)
      );
  }
```